# How could I avoid blank spaces in webpage? Unable to solve

Tags: css

Good afternoon,

Please could somebody help me in how to avoid the blank space that I have in my website. Thanks in advance for supporting. See website: https://total-manufacturing.com/. Please choose language Español in case automatically goes to English.

[Image of the blank space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRJPP.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] and take the [tour] to best understand how the site works and get helpful direction from the community.  Please note that [simply linking to your problem offsite is not considered sufficient per the site guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/6831341). You are expected to include a [mcve] of code in the body of the question itself, as well as steps to reproduce, the expected/desired outcome, and the actual outcome. Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

That´s because the height of the cars are diferents, the title of the first one has two lines but the other has only one, what you can do is wrap each 3 col-md-4 into a row, this will solve your problem, other solution is give a height to  .post-title, about 50 more or less, this will do all cards will have same height and will resolve your problem